# Middleware calls in express not stopped after returning inside one of them

Tags: javascript, express

I am having issues with middleware in my express app, I have the following route:

```
app.post(
    '/api/auth/signup',
    [
        verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
        verifySignUp.checkRolesExist
    ],
    controller.signup
);
```

There are the two middleware `checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail` and `checkRolesExist` as follows:

```
const checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail');
  User.findOne({username: req.body.username}).exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("user name exists");
        return fail(res, {message: 'This username already exists'});
      }
      return User.findOne({email: req.body.email}).exec()
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        return fail(res, {message: 'This email already exists'});
      }
      next();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);

      fail(res, {message: 'Database internal error occured.'});
    });
};

const checkRolesExist = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('checkRolesExist');
  console.log(req.body.roles);
    for (const role of req.body.roles) {
      if (!ROLES.includes(role)) {
        return fail(res, {message: `${role} is not a valid role`});
      }
    }
    next();
};

const fail = (res, err) => {
  const message = err.message || 'Encountered a server error';
  const status = err.status || 500;
  res.status(status).json({status, message});
}
```

I make a request with a username that has already been used before and in the console I get `user name exists` as expected however the app goes on to call `checkRolesExist`, shouldn't execution of middleware stop when it hits a return? What am I doing wrong where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `return fail` returns to... nothing. you're returning stuff inside the `then()` callback function, not inside `checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail()`. So, the execution keeps going, and you hit the next `.then()`.

Go `async/await` style, it will make your life easier :

```
const checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = async(req, res, next) => {

    console.log('checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail');

    try {
        if ( await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).exec() ) {
            console.log("user name exists");
            return fail(res, { message: 'This username already exists' });
        }

        if ( await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec()) {
            return fail(res, { message: 'This email already exists' });
        }
        next();

    } catch (error) {

        console.log(error);
        fail(res, { message: 'Database internal error occured.' });
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh damn, yes that makes sense. Is there no way to do this with promises? Seems like they are kind of useless for middleware because you can't return.

Comment: Why does the second api call `user = User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).exec();` not use `await`?

Comment: Ah, because my bad :) Fixed it

Comment: Also, I got rid of the `user` variable, it was useless except for readability

Comment: Why remove the `User` var?, doesn't is inform if the user is found or not? .e.g `null` if no user found and `user` if user found.

Comment: because it's useless. It's nice to have because it makes your code more readable, and also if you want to log it. But instead of `let a = true; if(a)...` you can do directly `if(true)`. Why add the variable `a`? Same here for `user`. `let user = await User.findOne(); if(user)...` why add a `user` variable when you can directly do `if( await User.findOne())`? But really, it's a matter of coding style. I would go lean and not add an extra variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to run in the specific order that `checkRolesExist` is not fired unless the first passes, then do this:

```
app.post(
    '/api/auth/signup',
    verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
    verifySignUp.checkRolesExist,
    controller.signup
);
```